# Pivot table with date types

Tags: mysql, sql, date, pivot, alias

i would like convert data from `Table1` as you can see on first picture on data in Pivot_table. I would like to count how many values are in grade field. Is possible to do that with date type in MySQL? Can i somehow use dynamically named aliases for example you can see it lower `AS NOW()`?

```
Table1:
PK        Date                     Subject       Grade
----------------------------------------------------
1         2013-09-11 10:37:45      History         A
2         2013-09-11 10:37:45      Math            B
3         2013-09-11 10:37:45      Math            A    
4         2013-09-11 10:37:45      Biology         D
5         2013-10-11 10:37:45      History         B
6         2013-10-11 10:37:45      History         A
7         2013-10-11 10:37:45      Math            A
8         2013-10-11 10:37:45      Geography       C
9         2013-10-11 10:37:45      Geography       A
10        2013-10-11 10:37:45      Geography       C


Pivot_table:
Subject     11-09-2013     11-10-2013
--------------------------------------
Math        2                 1
History     1                 2
Biology     1
Geography                     3


I tried something like this:

SELECT subject,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN date = CURRENT_DATE() THEN grade END) AS NOW(),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) THEN grade END) AS '11-09-2013',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN date = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AS '11-10-2013' 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY subject
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dynamic aliases is possible. You could generate the aliases name in your app.